# Moving Side Bar from Left to Right

Tags: css

I purchased a template which have left side Bar with  below properties :

```
.sidebar {
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
background: #fdfdfd;
width: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
height: calc(100vh - 70px);
position: fixed;
top: 70px;
left: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
z-index: 11 !important;
```

and content have below Properties :

```
    margin: 80px 315px 0 315px;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-o-transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;
```

I want to know how can I move Side bar from left to right of the content?

Note :By adding left:1040px of 100% to side bar ,it will move to left but will not be responsive to changing screen size.

Comment: please add your all html and css code.

Comment: So, you want it to move back and forth *dynamically*, or just to simply be on the right side instead of the left?

Comment: have you tried replacing `left: 0;` with `right: 0;`?

Comment: What's the template? It may be configurable in the options

Comment: Probably a combination of left and calc.

Comment: Can you add your html code?

Comment: Thanks All for your time, Thanks @ManuelOtto ,  I solved by your answer,Thanks again